# ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)

Tags: keras, h5py

I was running a similar model previously(But slightly different) and have been saving the weights only. I deleted all the h5 files after the modification of the model and it raised this error. I have searched all the possible answers but I can't find the solution for this.
I'm a bit frustrated at the moment. What can I do to solve this issue?

my model is

```
model_Unet_input = UNet(Input_layer)
model_SegNet_input = SegNet(Input_layer)

model_Unet_output = UNet.layers[-3].output
model_Segnet_output = SegNet.layers[-3].output

avg = tf.keras.layers.Average()([model_Unet_output,model_Segnet_output])
data_output1 = layers.Conv2D(2, 1, strides=1,kernel_initializer='he_normal')(avg)
data_ouput2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(data_output1)
model_Unet_SegNet = Model([UNet.input, SegNet.input],data_ouput2)

model_Unet_SegNet.summary()

model_Unet_SegNet_dir ='/nobackup/projects/bddur22/eunji/dissertation/model/saved_models/Unet_SegNet_avg'
model_Unet_SegNet.compile(adam_optimizer, total_loss, metrics=metrics)
model_Unet_SegNet_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(model_Unet_SegNet_dir,'ckpt', 'unet_seg_model-{epoch:03d}-{iou_score:03f}-{val_iou_score:03f}-{loss:03f}-{val_loss:03f}.h5'), monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')

print('model compile completed, model training starts',end='\n')

model_Unet_SegNet_history=model_Unet_SegNet.fit([x_train_processed_res,x_train_processed_res], 
y_train, verbose=1,batch_size = batch_size,
epochs = epochs,validation_data([x_val_processed_res,x_val_processed_res], y_val),
callbacks =[model_Unet_SegNet_checkpoint])
```

The error appears like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nobackup/projects/bddur22/eunji/dissertation/data/model_UNet_SegNet_avg_test.py", line 199, in <module>
    model_Unet_SegNet_history=model_Unet_SegNet.fit([x_train_processed_res,x_train_processed_res],
  File "/users/eunji/miniconda/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/users/eunji/miniconda/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 148, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, **kwds)
  File "/users/eunji/miniconda/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 137, in make_new_dset
    dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5d.pyx", line 87, in h5py.h5d.create
ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)
```

Comment: Is the error still there when you remove the callback? It is obvious that something attempts to create a duplicate dataset name in an HDF5 file. The question is, does the error come from code that you wrote, like the model or the checkpoint. Unfortunately, the traceback seems incomplete. Try putting print statements into your code to see if it happens inside any code you wrote

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the layer names are duplicates across the namespaces of the pre-trained model and your downstream-task network. It may be useful if you choose to call every layer of your downstream task network with unique names.  Add a `name='some_unique_name'` to all the layers you create to solve the problem.

```
data_output1 = layers.Conv2D(2, 1, strides=1,kernel_initializer='he_normal',name='conv_2d_output_1')(avg)
```